# Cannot kill a Postgres query

Tags: postgresql

So, this is a problem I've had a few times – where I'll accidentally do a SELECT * from a giant database. Normally, I just go in, get the pid of the query (SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity), and then do a SELECT pg_cancel_backend(PID here), and voilà, it ends. But sometimes – especially with queries that will eventually yield a ridiculous number of rows – it just returns this:

```
db=# select pg_cancel_backend(5246);
 pg_cancel_backend
-------------------
 t
(1 row)
```

...and the query lives on! How do I kill these things??

Comment: if you're on Unix, you may have to `kill -9 <pid>`.  Every once in a while I get one of those.

Comment: You can certainly kill -9 the backend, but that should be an absolute last resort, as it can end up corrupting the database.  If that happens, it could take a long time to restart while it rolls the transaction log forward to the last good point.

Answer (score 0):

I would try pg_terminate_backend(pid);